# AVAudioPlayer setVoume:x, when x > 1.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

I have been working with AVAudioPlayer on the iPad (original version) running IOS 4.3.3

The documentation for the volume property states:

**"The playback gain for the audio player, ranging from 0.0 through 1.0."**

Curiously it seems to allow you to use a value > 1.0, with the expected effect (the volume is increased accordingly). This means if you are playing a quieter track, you can (for example) mix it at volume 2.0 with the line

```
[myPlayer setVolume:2.0];
```

Reading back the volume property returns 2.0 as the current value.

so my question is: is this a mistake in the documentation, or a bug we can expect to be rectified in later releases?

It does turn out to be a useful feature, however does have potential to increase the playback volume to "over zero", should the audio being played happen to contain samples which when multiplied by the volume are over the supported bit resolution. In my app i am planning on using it to "level match" playback levels after scanning the audio.

Otherwise I'd need to turn down "loud" tracks to a predetermined nominal zero value, and not turn down the "quiet" tracks as much. It makes more sense to be able to increase the volume of the quieter tracks to actual "zero", thus giving more overall dynamic range.